# Problema ao atualizar composer

Tags: php, composer, windows-10

Estou a seguinte versão do php

```
PHP 7.2.19 (cli) (built: May 29 2019 13:58:59) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Estou usando o extension_dir do php no caminho

```
extension_dir = "C:/WEBSERVER/PHP7.2/ext"
```

Liberei a extensão openssl no php.ini

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Essa extensão está presente na pasta ext

Quando rodo o composer update ou composer install

Dá a seguinte mensagem

```
 [Composer\Exception\NoSslException]
  The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.


config [-g|--global] [-e|--editor] [-a|--auth] [--unset] [-l|--list] [-f|--file FILE] [--absolute] [--] [<setting-key>] [<setting-value>]...
```

Já tentei rodar o seguinte comando:

```
 composer config -g -- disable-tls true
```

Porém o erro anterior se repete..

O php que estou usando é Thread safe

Answer (score 0):

Usar somente o caminho relativo para o diretório das seus extensões já é o suficiente:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

Se quiser usar o caminho absoluto, lembre-se que o Windows utiliza barra invertida para separar os diretórios:

```
extension_dir = "C:\WEBSERVER\PHP7.2\ext"
```

Comment: Somente com o "ext" não funciona

Comment: O php está configurado no seu PATH? Aqui eu uso só ext sem problemas

Comment: Sim. Quando dou o php -version ele mostra